# How to customize PDF in Tableau?

Tags: javascript, tableau-api, dom-events

I would like to know if anyone can help me with the customization of the PDF content of Tableau visualization.
At the moment is displaying only the image of the visualization.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What else do you want it to show besides the visualization?

Answer (score 1):

How are you exporting to PDF? By going to File->Print as PDF?

You can add title and caption to a sheet and its export to pdf by selecting the option in worksheet-> show title/show caption.

A better option is to create a dashboard. Drag your sheet into it and then you can add text/images/breaks to the canvas. This will then be included in the pdf when you go to File-Print to PDF.

More detailed information:

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/tips-printing-and-print-pdf

Comment: Hello, we are using Tableau JavaScript API. Any ideas on that?

Comment: No, cant help you there I'm afraid. I would guess updating the source tableau file should update it for the js export to pdf call? But I have not used the js api so just guessing.